# Opacity for reference image not working

Tags: image, transparency

[image: example of issue]

Currently trying to do some modeling using reference images, and found out that in my current blender install (2.90.1) for some reason the image transparency does not work. I'm modifying the transparency using Object Data Properties, ticking the transparency box and adjusting opacity as shown in the attached image. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I asked a more detailed version of this question (with more screenshots and a link to a tutorial where the transparency feature worked as expected) here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/how-can-i-set-reference-images-to-semi-transparent-in-blender-2-93-2 Hopefully the extra detail will lead to a good answer.

Comment: I believe this is caused by an issue with Intel Graphics on Linux; are you using Intel Graphics on Linux? https://developer.blender.org/T77572